# xslt change output based on service responce

Tags: xml, xslt, soap

I am transforming XML files such as this ...

```
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <swiftResponseResponse xmlns="http://webservice.sbi.com">
         <swiftResponseReturn>15617TS006140|DC768736|13321.49|04-05-2017 15:13:03|SWIFTINR|NA|FAIL-ACCOUNT UNAVAILABLE</swiftResponseReturn>
      </swiftResponseResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

... via this XSL stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://webservice.sbi.com" exclude-result-prefixes="soapenv xsl  xsd xsi xs ">
       <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
       <xsl:template name="tokenize">
              <xsl:param name="text"/>
              <xsl:param name="separator" />
              <xsl:param name="index" select="1"/>
              <xsl:choose>
                     <xsl:when test="not(contains($text, $separator))">
                           <xsl:element name="swiftResponseReturnValue_{$index}">
                                  <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
                           </xsl:element>
                     </xsl:when>
                     <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:element name="swiftResponseReturnValue_{$index}">
                                  <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(substring-before($text, $separator))"/>
                           </xsl:element>
                           <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
                                  <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, $separator)"/>
                                  <xsl:with-param name="separator" select="$separator"/>
                                  <xsl:with-param name="index" select="$index + 1"/>
                           </xsl:call-template>
                     </xsl:otherwise>
              </xsl:choose>
       </xsl:template>
       <xsl:template match="xs:swiftResponseReturn">
              <swiftResponseReturn>
                     <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
                           <xsl:with-param name="text" select="."/>
                           <xsl:with-param name="separator" select="'|'"/>
                     </xsl:call-template>
              </swiftResponseReturn>
       </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

For the given example input XML, this transform produces the desired result:

```
<swiftResponseReturn>
    <swiftResponseReturnValue_1>15617TS006140</swiftResponseReturnValue_1>
    <swiftResponseReturnValue_2>DC768736</swiftResponseReturnValue_2>
    <swiftResponseReturnValue_3>13321.49</swiftResponseReturnValue_3>
    <swiftResponseReturnValue_4>04-05-2017 15:13:03</swiftResponseReturnValue_4>
    <swiftResponseReturnValue_5>SWIFTINR</swiftResponseReturnValue_5>
    <swiftResponseReturnValue_6>NA</swiftResponseReturnValue_6>
    <swiftResponseReturnValue_7>FAIL-ACCOUNT UNAVAILABLE</swiftResponseReturnValue_7>
</swiftResponseReturn>
```

In the event of incorrect application input, however, the XML arriving for transformation has this form instead:

```
 <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <swiftResponseResponse xmlns="http://webservice.sbi.com">
         <swiftResponseReturn>15617TS006140||NO RECORDS FOUND</swiftResponseReturn>
      </swiftResponseResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The resulting XML output is ...

```
    <swiftResponseReturn>
    <swiftResponseReturnValue_1>15617TS006140</swiftResponseReturnValue_1>
    <swiftResponseReturnValue_2/>
    <swiftResponseReturnValue_3>NO RECORDS FOUND</swiftResponseReturnValue_3>
</swiftResponseReturn>
```

... but in that case I want to produce this result:

```
  <swiftResponseReturn>
                <swiftResponseReturnValue_1>15617TS006140</swiftResponseReturnValue_1>
                <swiftResponseReturnValue_2></swiftResponseReturnValue_2>
                <swiftResponseReturnValue_3></swiftResponseReturnValue_3>
                <swiftResponseReturnValue_4></swiftResponseReturnValue_4>
                <swiftResponseReturnValue_5></swiftResponseReturnValue_5>
                <swiftResponseReturnValue_6></swiftResponseReturnValue_6>
                <swiftResponseReturnValue_7>NO RECORDS FOUND</swiftResponseReturnValue_7>
</swiftResponseReturn>
```

.  How can I modify the stylesheet to produce the above output in the invalid-input case, but still produce the same output it does now in the valid-input case?

Comment: any suggestion its possible or not?

Comment: So what, exactly, is the logic you want here?  Maybe that if there are fewer than seven `|`-delimited fields that enough empty fields are synthesized to fill out the count to seven?  Is the presence of an actual empty field supposed to be taken into account in any way?  What if more than seven fields are present in the input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I infer from your desired output that you want there always to be exactly `<swiftResponseReturnValue_*>` elements in the output tree, with empty elements inserted *before* the last, if necessary, to pad the count to that number.  Your stylesheet can be modified to do that.

Presently, your "tokenize" template tests whether it has reached the last element by whether the separator string appears in the provided text.  That's not what you want; instead you must change to a criterion based on the number of elements so far emitted, which it can determine from its `$index` parameter.

You want the same behavior for each of the first six elements:

- emit a return value element containing the substring of the current text preceding the separator, if there is any
- recurse

For the seventh element, on the other hand, you can just emit a return value containing the tail of the text.  The only catch is that when `tokenize` recurses, the value it must bind to the `$text` parameter depends on whether the separator string appears in the current text.  If so, it must send the substring after the separator; otherwise, it must send the whole text.  There is no built-in function that will do that, but you can do it via XSL elements in the `xsl:with-param` body.

Here's a variation along those lines that produces your desired output for each input:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xs="http://webservice.sbi.com"
    exclude-result-prefixes="soapenv xsl xsd xsi xs">

  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template name="tokenize">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:param name="separator" />
    <xsl:param name="index" select="1"/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$index &lt; 7">
        <xsl:element name="swiftResponseReturnValue_{$index}">
          <!-- substring-before() returns an empty string when the separator
               string is not found -->
          <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(substring-before($text, $separator))"/>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
          <xsl:with-param name="text">
            <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="contains($text, $separator)">
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($text, $separator)"/>
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
              </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
          </xsl:with-param>
          <xsl:with-param name="separator" select="$separator"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="index" select="$index + 1"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <swiftResponseReturnValue_7>
          <!-- the tail goes into the seventh return value -->
          <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
        </swiftResponseReturnValue_7>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="xs:swiftResponseReturn">
    <swiftResponseReturn>
      <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="."/>
        <xsl:with-param name="separator" select="'|'"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </swiftResponseReturn>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```